# Add custom directive for strftime in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to add a `%custom` directive to `strfime` that will translate months to the code used in some financial/trading reports

- January =>    F
- February =>   G
- March =>  H
- April =>  J
- May =>    K
- June =>   M
- July =>   N
- August => Q
- September =>  U
- October =>    V
- November =>   X
- December =>   Z

I've tried finding documentation on this but was not able to find. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directives are hardcoded in `strftime.c` and cannot be extended.

Maybe try this?

```
months = { "Jan" => "F", "Feb" => "G", ... }
Date.today.strftime('%b %d, %Y').gsub(Regexp.union(months.keys), months)
# => "F 08, 2017"
```

Comment: Thanks for such a rapid answer @akuhn